# Exactly how much programming will I be doing if I work as a hardware design engineer?

Tags: hardware

I have a question for current hardware design engineers or others, closely related to that field.

Say I want to be a computer hardware engineer for the automotive industry. I very much like working with hardware, but much less fond of writing software. I heard however that I will have to write the software to command the hardware I build/test.

How much programming skills do I need? Approximately what part of my job (in %) will consist of writing computer programs? How advanced will my programming ability need to be (for example, will the skill level acquired in CS I, CS II and Data Structures courses offered in most universities be enough)?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Thank you all for the replies. I did get an idea what the job will be like in regard to programming. I already have decent skills in C++, Java and Bash scripting, so I was wondering how much of my time will consist of pure programming, but as I see, it varies greatly. Again, thanks for the replies, they were really helpful.

Comment: You can get away with none, but you'll be a lot more valuable as an engineer if you can sling some code.

Comment: Apparently you won't get a job not matching your skills, so don't worry. And as for learning - do as much as you can.

Comment: The answer to this question is a very definite "it depends" I do a lot of both hardware and software / firmware.  But I know a lot of engineers who are exclusively one or the other.

Comment: @WarrenHill And I know some who can do neither :)

Comment: *Exactly how much programming* You make it sound like an engineer's job is entirely predictable. **Well it's not**. In some years all I did was write some shell scripts, last year I learned myself to use Matlab (Octave actually) and Python. Life is so much easier when you can do your own coding. Oh, I design hardware, **analog hardware that sits on a chip**. If you do not want to code, you better become a dentist (or a manger ;-) ).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about engineering careers rather than a specific engineering problem to be solved.

Comment: You can be one or the other, but you are more likely to get a good job if you can do well in both.

Comment: As regards the level of code required, you might get by with cut/paste coding, and some debug (as a minimum). Scripting and control flow, plus supporting some heavy c++ would not be unusual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are a hardware designer in a normal-sized company you will almost never code anything, apart from your own personal test code (time a response, flash some leds, make sure the different interfaces are functioning, etc.). If you are in a small company and they can only afford to hire you, you will be doing what you can and people will be screaming at you for no reason, thinking you are a one-man army. I wouldn't recommend it.

The responsibilities of a hardware designer is to elaborate the schematics from the problem analysis documents, construct prototypes, test, debug, optimize cost, test more, debug more, and figure out how to package it all in the smallest enclosure possible, while respecting constraints. You will have more than enough to do without ALSO having to develop a full software stack. If they insist you have to do it all, I would suggest asking them to pay you both salaries anyway.

Comment: *your own personal test code* can be pretty sophisticated

Comment: @Eugene Sh. But often has nothing to do with the actual application. Most of my test code is mostly a command interpreter sitting on the UART or SPI, with LED tests, wireless tests, filesystem tests, etc...

Comment: Which means that you might need to know how to program and debug these.

Comment: Yes, agreed. You pretty much **need** to know at least **some** programming anyway, just to be able to read a MCU/CPU datasheet. The question was not about if you need to know how to code, but how often will you write code. Usually, not very often. I have worked on a year-long project last year, a small embedded platform running on an ARM Cortex, I spent maybe 10 hours total coding.

Comment: Part of it was "How much programming skills do I need", anyway.

Comment: The answer is still "not much at all"... I mean as long as you know how to read and write from and to memory and pins, you don't need much more than this.

Answer (score 0):

It's always useful for a HW engineer to be able to write code, not necessarily in the sense of architecting some grandoise software application, but it's extremely useful to be able to sling scripts around. Python and Tcl (plus bash) come to mind -- lots of tool-flows have scripting interfaces, and they often leverage these two languages. Will you be writing the best, most performant, algorithmically pure code? No. Will you sling something together that won't win a beauty contest but end up saving your team hours in the long run (assuming you don't have a tools guy)? Heck yes.

Personally I have a bit of a software background, so I'm happy to sling around C, Python and Tcl. When it comes to designing boards with SoCs and such, it is very helpful to have a blending / cross-over at low-level  where the HW guy knows enough to work with that code and modify it as necessary.

Specifics of course will vary based on your job title, but I feel 100% comfortable saying knowing how to write basic scripts in Python or bash can only help you in your career. That knowledge can be picked up in a couple of hours from some great tutorial websites, assuming you've got the basics down (don't most EE degrees now at least require CS 101?).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do real, conceptual design and advance in your career, I would recommend you to become capable in imbedded firmware as well as hardware.  Someone has to make the trade-offs when designs are initiated, and knowledge of what is practical, processor speed vs. overhead vs. power vs. packaging requires a good grasp of all of the facets.  There are almost no designs left without a processor of some type.  I know there are firmware specialists who are quite happy staring at the screen all day, and hardware guys who try to avoid all firmware.  But if you are a systems guy, you will need to be able to do both.  My experience is that the firmware takes longer if it is part of your job, but even if you have a firmware guy assigned to a project you need to be able to troubleshoot at the code level.